# Быть на верху блаженства vs быть наверху блаженства

Tags: правописание, синтаксис

According to [this source](http://phraseology.academic.ru/1031/%D0%9D%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D1%83_%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) one should write

> На верху блаженства

According to [this source](http://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/57/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9) (from the same site) one should write

> Наверху блаженства

I wonder, what is correct?

My hypothesis:

Быть наверху блаженства = be in a highly joyful state.

Быть на верху блаженства = be in at the maximum of joy (better than before and after).

Comment: Judging by answers below, there is evidence for both, therefore one must learn not deduce it. Maybe this will help - yet this is also just an answer. http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1374658-kak-pravilno-pisat-naverhu-blazhenstva-ili-na-verhu-blazhenstva.html

Comment: Задал Ваш вопрос, Anixx, на "Русский язык бета". С тем, что можно писать "на верху блаженства" и "наверху блаженства" никто спорить, естественно, не стал (двоякое написание зафиксировано в словарях); а вот с Вашей гипотезой никто там пока не согласился. Смысл фразы в обоих случаях один: тот, который дан в Вашей первой ссылке.

Comment: Я хочу выяснить, появляется ли смысловая разница при разном написании, или её нет. –  Матвей Дёмин 1 час назад 
   
Матвей, если бы была какая-нибудь смысловая разница, словарями она фиксировалась бы. –  Серж 1 час

Comment: Vera, а разница в семантике "на верху блаженства" и "наверху блаженства" есть? –  Матвей Дёмин 35 мин. назад   
  
Думаю, что нет. Даже для предметных существительных смысловую разницу трудно уловить, а здесь речь идет об отвлеченном понятии. –  Vera 31 мин. назад

Comment: Это в подтверждение своих слов скопировал на "Русский язык бета".

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку словосочетание "верх блаженства" вполне устойчиво, то и раздельное написание в случае "на верху блаженства" представляется вполне верным.

А что значит "наверху блаженства" - мне не понятно. Выше чем само блаженство, что ли? По-моему, это ошибка.

Comment: Нет, это предлог такой. Читайте Розенталя.

Comment: @behemothus Не каждый предлог можно использовать бездумно. "Наверху" - это либо "вверху", либо "в верхней части". Ни то ни другое значение со словом "блаженство" никак не сочетается. Читайте толковый словарь русского языка.

Comment: А что не телефонную книгу? И не з=\

Comment: А что не телефонную книгу? )))) Понимаете, все ваши "умные" рассуждения разбиваются о Розенталя. Вы ему тоже посоветуете "словарь читать"? И какой кстати? Кузнецова? Он путаник великий.

Comment: @behemothus Любой толковый словарь. "Верх блаженства" - это устойчивое словосочетание. Нельзя взять и просто приписать к нему две буквы слева. И никакие розентали тут значения не имеют - это литературная традиция. Найдите такое у Пушкина, и я сразу же признаю себя неправым.

Comment: А кто такой Пушкин? Не напомните, когда он умер? И сколько ошибок у него было в черновиках? Объясните, почему Розенталь неправ - я может быть и продолжу.

Comment: Кстати, Делвиг -- Пушкину  пойдет?))) https://books.google.ru/books?id=CEP3CAAAQBAJ&pg=PT60&lpg=PT60&dq=%22%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D1%83+%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%22+%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD&source=bl&ots=HgFqAo6rYV&sig=PCata-70h4arj0h7IQO3TKxcUhs&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0CCoQ6AEwA2oVChMIzv-twtORxwIVI_ByCh0yOw4c#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D1%83%20%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%22%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD&f=false

Comment: @behemothus Почему неправ, я уже объяснил: идиомы фиксируются исключительно литературной традицией. Т.к. устная для проверки правописания не годится, нужно письменное свидетельство. А вот объяснения, почему он прав, я от Вас так и не дождался. Что касается Пушкина, то он умел писать, а потому пользуется кредитом доверия. Это означает, что, хотя он может быть иногда неправ, но в отсутствие иных аргументов я готов ему верить на слово, а всяким прочим - нет. Если смущает век, найдите, скажем, у Булгакова.

Comment: Да? А я простите, думал, что это флуд))) Извините, никак не могу принять всерьез ваши рассуждения. Значит, Пушкин умел, а ошибки в сочинениях делал из принципа? А вот Розенталь ошибается? Уважаемый, вам надо - вы и ищите.

Comment: @behemothus Дельвиг писал от руки. В разных изданиях это письмо цитируют по-разному: кто "на верху", кто "наверху". Так что это на совести редакторов.

Comment: @behemothus Флудите Вы, т.к. никакой аргументации кроме апелляции к авторитету не имеете.

Comment: Ну знаете, а Пушкин не на совести редакторов? А некто с цифровым ником - не на совести? А Булгаков? Меня не век смущает, а ваше полное непонимание того, что действующие правила утверждены в 1954 г. И вот после них и пошла вся катавасия с раздельным написанием того, что раньше последовательно писалось слитно. Там просто не оговорены все случаи, которые есть у Розенталя. Естественно, что вы не сказав ни слова по сути того **почему** он ошибся, опровергнуть его не можете.  Все, вопрос закрыт.

Comment: @behemothus Только не надо притворяться, что Вы не знаете, что тексты Пушкина, сверяются по прижизненным изданиям и спискам, а также, что он сам исполнял редакторские обязанности. Если Вас смущает 1954 г., так найдите приличного литератора после 1954 г., кто ж Вам запрещает? И не трожьте мой ник, я же Ваш не трогаю.

Comment: Я не притворяюсь. Вы реально не ответил неа вопрос, почему вы считаете себя вправе "опровергать" Розенталя методами, присущими более распальцованному жлобу, а не человку, рассуддающему о Пушкине. (Примерно: "он не прав, потому что я, 4419802-й юзер, так считаю"). При чем тут ник? Ваш уровень **аргументации ниже всякой критики. ** DIXI.

Comment: @behemothus Во-первых, научитесь вести себя достойно и не упоминайте Вашего собеседника в одном предложении с неприличными словами - это Вас не красит. Во-вторых, я уже дважды объяснял свою аргументацию, но если так трудно перечитать написанное, могу повторить в третий раз: словосочетание "наверху блаженства" не имеет самостоятельного смысла, а идиома "наверху блаженства" не встречается в литературе (или по крайней мере я ее не встречал). Если есть чем ответить по существу - ответьте. В-третьих, Вы уже второй раз склоняете мой ник, но при этом переспрашиваете "При чем тут ник".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26614/discussion-between-behemothus-and-user4419802).

Answer (score 0):

@Anixx, **"наверху блаженства"** is correct,

In this expression "наверху" is the so-called "непревообразный предлог" (non-primitive? preposition). It is not divided into two semantic parts, so there it is stored joint-spelling.

read more here (in Russian)

http://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/57/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9
Пункт 7. "Примечание 2"

> Быть наверху блаженства = be in a highly joyful state.
>
> Быть на верху блаженства = be in at the maximum of joy (better than
>   before and after).

These expressions are very closed in Russian, the same mean practically.
Both cases need joint spell.

Answer (score -2):

"Быть на верху блаженства" - корявая фраза. "Наверху блаженства" не "бывают", а пребывают. :) Типа "Пребывал на верху блаженства". 
 В литературном произведениии, "пребывание на верху блаженства" обычно продолжается не долго, после чего следует "холодный душ" и низвержение в адский холод бренного существования.

Comment: Усугублю. 
"Пребывал на вершине блаженства."
Другие варианты - коверканье русского языка, IMHO.